# How to read formatted text?

Tags: ruby, text-formatting

Suppose I have a string with the following content:

```
TODO    | Eat spaghetti.               | High   | food, happiness
TODO    | Get 8 hours of sleep.        | Low    | health
CURRENT | Party animal.                | Normal | socialization
CURRENT | Grok Ruby.                   | High   | development, ruby
DONE    | Have some tea.               | Normal |
TODO    | Destroy Facebook and Google. | High   | save humanity, conspiracy
TODO    | Hunt saber-toothed cats.     | Low    | wtf
DONE    | Do the 5th Ruby challenge.   | High   | ruby course, FMI, development, ruby
TODO    | Find missing socks.          | Low    |
CURRENT | Grow epic mustache.          | High   | sex appeal
```

What is the best way to read such content and store it in objects say with the following structure:

```
class example
  attr_accessor status
  attr_accessor description
  attr_accessor priority
  attr_accessor tags
end
```

I tried with the following regex:

```
 /[a-zA-Z0-9]*/.match(text above)
```

But all I get is

```
#<MatchData "TODO">
```

What I expected to get is

```
[TODO, Eat spaghetti, High, food, happiness, TODO ... etc ]
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just split lines with `|` and strip it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use string.split rather than regex.match
see the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split)

Answer (score 0):

`"TODO    | Eat spaghetti.               | High   | food, happiness".split('|')`

```
=> ["TODO    ", " Eat spaghetti.               ", " High   ", " food, happiness"]
```

OR

```
"TODO    | Eat spaghetti.               | High   | food, happiness".scan(/[^|]+/)

=>  ["TODO    ", " Eat spaghetti.               ", " High   ", " food, happiness"]
```

OR

```
"TODO    | Eat spaghetti.               | High   | food, happiness".split('|').map{ |i| i.strip }
=> ["TODO", "Eat spaghetti.", "High", "food, happiness"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.each_line.map{|l| l.strip.split(/\s*\|\s*/)}
```

Result:

```
[
  ["TODO", "Eat spaghetti.", "High", "food, happiness"],
  ["TODO", "Get 8 hours of sleep.", "Low", "health"],
  ["CURRENT", "Party animal.", "Normal", "socialization"],
  ["CURRENT", "Grok Ruby.", "High", "development, ruby"],
  ["DONE", "Have some tea.", "Normal"],
  [
    "TODO",
    "Destroy Facebook and Google.",
    "High",
    "save humanity, conspiracy"
  ],
  ["TODO", "Hunt saber-toothed cats.", "Low", "wtf"],
  [
    "DONE",
    "Do the 5th Ruby challenge.",
    "High",
    "ruby course, FMI, development, ruby"
  ],
  ["TODO", "Find missing socks.", "Low"],
  ["CURRENT", "Grow epic mustache.", "High", "sex appeal"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the data into classes we need 4 steps:

First get the data in memory:

```
file = 'path/to/my/file.txt'
raw_data = File.read(file)
```

Parse the data by taking each line, split it by | and then strip white spaces and new lines.

```
parsed_data = raw_data.lines.map{|line| line.split('|').map(&:strip)}
p parsed_data.first #=> ["TODO", "Eat spaghetti.", "High", "food, happiness"]
```

Define class Example:

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :status, :description :priority, :tags

  def initialize(status, description, priority, tags)
    @status, @description, @priority = status, description, priority
    @tags = tags.split(', ') # Split tags and store in a list.
  end

end
```

Create the new objects:

```
list_of_examples = parsed_data.map{|line| Example.new(*line)}
p list_of_examples.first #=> #<Example:0x2212ae8 @priority="High", @description="Eat spaghetti.", @status="TODO", @tags=["food", "happiness"]>
```